# Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 won't autocomplete newly added NuGet packages

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

I have recently added new NuGet packages (and references) to my project, but when I start typing my code, VS won't autocomplete or even offer me classes which should be now be available. So, if I would like to reference some class from newly added package, I must manually type 'using NewlyAddedPackage...'. It is pretty annoying and I can't continue my work like this. Any suggestions why is this happening and how can I fix it?

To be clear, I installed NuGet package for FluentNHibernate and when i try to write code like:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerMap : ClassMap<Customer>
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

when I start typing ClassMap... autocomplete won't offer ClassMap from FluentNHibernate.Mapping namespace. NuGet package is properly installed in project and I can see it in Project>Refferences list. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completion list is a part of [Visual C# IntelliSense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-csharp-intellisense) feature, it works fine, just not exactly the way you expected.

In absence of `using` directives within current file completion list offers you everything that is declared in [`global`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/global) namespace. You can access newly added types using fully qualified name `global::FluentNHibernate.Mapping.ClassMap` which is same as `FluentNHibernate.Mapping.ClassMap` most of the time. For exceptions see [Use the Global Namespace Alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/how-to-use-the-global-namespace-alias) article on MSDN. To make things easier `using` directive is typically used to import types from a certain namespace, so you don't have to fully qualify name of the type. Visual Studio doesn't add `using` directives automatically. You have to either add them by hand or utilize [Quick Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quick-actions) feature (a light bulb, default key combination is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>) of a Visual Studio:
[image: Quick Action usage example]